# Incremental disk image backup for linux

Tags: linux, backup, windows-server-2012, disk-image, incremental-backup

I have 4 RHEL+2 windows workstations and 1 windows 2012 server. I want to take incremental backup of Linux to windows server. Is it possible to do this. I mean windows to windows is possible but is there any "Incremental image backup" utility (totally free) to handle "Linux->Windows Server".
My setup is very small 6 workstations + 1 Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be done by using rsync with hardlinking.
rsync checks if the source files have changed an then copies only the changed part. 
hardlinking reduces the amount of needed space.

1. create space On Server 2012: Setup a share for the backups via Servermanager.
2. write a small shell script, that mounts the share as samba share on the RHEL
3. rsyncs your backup into the mounted folders
4. run them in your backup schedule via ´cron´

Here you can find the docs: http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/

Things to consider when using rsync on windows partitions:

[ServerFault- What is archive mode](https://serverfault.com/questions/141773/what-is-archive-mode-in-rsync)

and modify window for FAT32

```
rysnc --modify-window=1 /source /target
```

this is because FAT32 uses a 2 second resolution for access times on files.

Here is also an explanation for syncing files the other way round. Maybe with the cygwinrsync solution its possible to manage the backup from the server instead form the clients:

[Using rsync and cygwin to Sync Files from a Linux Server to a Windows Notebook PC](http://www.trueblade.com/knowledge/using-rsync-and-cygwin-to-sync-files-from-a-linux-server-to-a-windows-notebook-pc)

Comment: I don't think windows filesystems (NTFS) support hardlinking, so all your data will probably be duplicated.

Comment: before downvoting, please take a small look to google:[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)

Comment: This does not seem to provide the same functionality as hardlinks, since it only works on directories: this means that if in each directory one file changed, then no "junction points" can be created and no space saved. Secondly, the question is if `rsync` actually makes use of this feature.

Comment: Well, MSDN also refers to this feature as " hard links" and also gives examples for files: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx) and the hardlinking rsync backup is used for windows machines in a popular script created by german c't [Hybrid-Backup](http://www.heise.de/ct/artikel/Sicherungs-Jongleur-1872485.html) german. Please back up your opinion by facts or provide a better solution to the question.

Comment: Ok, you showed me wrong (I never claimed that I was sure though). If you make an edit, then I can revert my downvote.

Comment: never intended to be rude, sorry for that. added some more info to the answer.